# get last 8 bits from int and covert to unsigned char

Tags: c, bit

I am trying to get the last 8 bits from a int and copy them in an unsigned char

Ex: int 2 -> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011

I want to get the 00000011 and copy the bits in an unsigned char
Can anyone please help me with some information?

Comment: Is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011` supposed to be the binary representation of the decimal number 3 or is it supposed to be the memory layout of the `int` on a specific system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char bottomByte = num & 0xff;
```

This will mask your `num` with `1111 1111` - leaving only the bottom eight bits.

---

Code like

```
unsigned char bottomByte = num;
```

will also work fine, assuming `num` is positive (or unsigned) - it will leave only the bottom byte of `num` in the unsigned char. But for clarity you should stick to `num & 0xff`.

Comment: `unsigned char bottomByte = num;` is likely to generate a warning.

Comment: @Evg Not in gcc.

Comment: `-Wimplicit-int-conversion`

Comment: @Evg I think in newer versions of gcc this is now `-Wconversion`.. good to know :) it's not included under `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

Comment: Many IDEs do things like static analysis while typing, so you get many more "yellow flags" and "squiggly lines." So `= num;` will be one of them ;)

Anyway, not sure if assignment is actually non-portable. When it comes to integral types, their bits are always presented in a natural order (big-endian,) regardless of how the CPU actually stores them. So when you assign `int` to `char`, the correct bits should end up in the `char`.  This is also why `num & 0xff` works. If you had to deal with endianess at the language level, you'd have to do `(num & 0xff000000) >> 24` depending on endianess.

Comment: @NikosC. Per the standard, `unsigned char bottomByte = num;` will place the bottom byte in memory of `num` in `bottomByte` - so in big-endian systems you will get a different result than in little-endian systems. But in `num & 0xff`, you're computing the mathematical bit-and computation, which is independent of the representation in memory.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, btw.) The actual rule says: "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2^n, where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. That is, depending on whether the destination type is wider or narrower, signed integers are sign-extended or truncated and unsigned integers are zero-extended or truncated respectively." So it seems to me that In this case, the destination type is narrower, so it's simply truncated.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: @NikosC. I'm wondering if there's a difference between C and C++ with regards to type conversion, because I do remember reading that in C the result of the cast is the lower byte in memory.. But I'm having difficulty finding this in the standard. I did find a mention here - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch04.html - but I'm not sure how reliable a source this is.

Comment: Per the C standard (2018 6.3.1.3 2), `unsigned char bottomByte = num;` will place the residue of `num` modulo 256 (for eight-bit `unsigned char`) in `bottomByte`. Endianness is irrelevant. The only way this might differ from the “bottom” (low-position-value) bits is if `num` is negative (including negative zero) and the C implementation uses one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks! Also goes to show that books can be unreliable :)

Comment: You should remove everything about portability and endianess from the answer, since it's incorrect.

Comment: `unsigned char bottomByte = num & 0xff;` also has the advantage of being independent of the implementation's `CHAR_BIT` value.

Comment: @IanAbbott But if `CHAR_BIT != 8` you probably don't want to mask with `0xff`, you're probably interested in the real lower "char"

Comment: @DanielKleinstein But the question title is "get last 8 bits ...".

Comment: @IanAbbott Because presumably OP is running on a system where `CHAR_BIT == 8` :). I just meant that if OP was now running on a system where `CHAR_BIT != 8`, the question would have been "how can I get the last {CHAR_BIT} bits?" and `0xff` wouldn't fit anymore.